# Eliminar los parrafos al dar click sobre mi elemento li

Tags: javascript

```
<p>
        Al contrario del pensamiento popular
    </p>
    <p id="pp">
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el .
    </p>
    <ul id="lista">
        <li>Estudiante</li>
        <li>Saul</li>
        <li onclick="eliminar();" id="borrar">Alex</li>
        <li>Onate</li>
        <li >Pluas</li>            
      </ul>
```

Este algoritmo me vota errores y no elimina los parrafos.
Necesito eliminar los parrafos al dar click sobre el elemento Alex.

Comment: Faltaría adjuntar el código de javascript que has intentado, para poder continuar desde ahí y ver en que has cometido errores.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- Esto eliminaria los parrafos al hacer click sobre "Alex": -->
```

```
<p>
        Al contrario del pensamiento popular
    </p>
    <p id="pp">
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el .
    </p>
    <ul id="lista">
        <li>Estudiante</li>
        <li>Saul</li>
        <li onclick="eliminar();" id="borrar">Alex</li>
        <li>Onate</li>
        <li >Pluas</li>            
      </ul>
 <script>
          function eliminar(){
            let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p');
            parrafos.forEach(parrafo => {
                parrafo.remove();
            });
        }
  </script>
```